# Threejs apply clipping to specific area of the object

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm using THREE.Plane to clip my STL model.

```
localPlane = new THREE.Plane( new THREE.Vector3( 0, -1, 0 ), 4);
.
.
.
material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( {
    color: 0xffffff,
    side: THREE.DoubleSide,
    clippingPlanes: [
        localPlane,
    ],
    clipShadows: true
} );
```

It's working; but the problem is that the whole object's top is clipped by this infinity sized plane. I want it to clip just a small part of it (It seems that there is no way to scale THREE.Plane)

I also tried using ThreeCSG.js but it seems inconvenient with STL objects!

Here is what I get:
[image: The whole model is cut through top]

Comment: Can you provide an image example showing what you mean by "clip just a small part of it"? And yes, `THREE.Plane` in infinite, as are clipping planes you provide to a material.

Comment: @TheJim01 I added an image

Comment: Yes, the image you've shared is the expected behavior. But what do you _expect_ to see? For example, do you only want the clip to apply to a single grid of your floor?

Comment: @TheJim01 I want it to apply only to half of the bone's top and the other half remain uncut. not cutting through the top.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the removal of the *intersection* of clipping planes is supported in three.js. You can use a pattern like this one:

```
// clipping planes
var localPlanes = [
    new THREE.Plane( new THREE.Vector3( - 1, 0, 0 ), 1 ),
    new THREE.Plane( new THREE.Vector3( 0, - 1, 0 ), 1 )
];

// material
var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( {
    color: 0xffffff,
    side: THREE.DoubleSide,
    clippingPlanes: localPlanes,
    clipIntersection: true
} );
```

Also, see the [three.js example](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_clipping_intersection.html).

three.js r.85

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes this is working but just for two planes. I must cut the bone to fit a prosthesis so I need several planes. when I add all the planes to the localPlanes array with clipIntersection enabled, nothing is clipped at all!

Comment: Thanks for bringing this up. I only found this after I had posted my response, and I like it much better than what I suggested, I just didn't have time to provide a new answer.

Comment: @TheJim01 Yes I must appreciate both of you guys for this. but my problem is that these two methods seem to be working for just two planes.

Comment: The example I linked to is using three clip planes.

Comment: @WestLangley I think there is a bug in three.js . The clipping is really "Intersected" when the clipIntersection is false, and "Union" when the clipIntersection is true!!!

Comment: No, there is no bug, it is just complicated, unfortunately... A clipping plane defines a half-space. The half-space consists of the points "in front of" the plane -- the side of the plane toward which the normal points. Clipping removes the complement of the half space. When `clipIntersection` is `true`, clipping retains the union of the half-spaces, and removes (clips) the _intersection_ of the complement of the half-spaces. When `clipIntersection` is `false`, clipping retains the intersection of the half-spaces, and removes (clips) the _union_ of the complement of the half-spaces.

Comment: @WestLangley Oh I got it! so the term "Intersection" and "Union" belong to the clipped area not the visible parts :)))
Thanks. I have one more question and I don't know if I should ask in a new thread or not, and that is: can I apply intersection just for some planes and keep the others clip the union?

Comment: You can, using both global and local clipping planes.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:** *Follow WestLangley's advice. I'll leave this her as an alternate though less efficient means of performing the clipping.*

Clipping planes are infinite. There's no getting around that. So what can you do? Multiple clipping planes in multiple render passes!

To do this, you'll need to turn off auto-clearing, and do your own manual buffer clearing.

```
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();    
renderer.autoClear = false;
```

Now let's say `plane1` is the clipping plane you currently have.

```
material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( {
    ...
    clippingPlanes: [
        plane1,
    ],
    clipShadows: true
} );

var myMesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
```

That clips the top half of `myMesh` when you call render. So you want to work with the remainder.

First, make another plane, `plane2`, be the inverse of `plane1`. `plane2` will then clip the BOTTOM of `myMesh`. But if you render one pass using `plane1`, and another using `plane2`, then you're back with a full mesh. So you'll need a third clip plane, `plane3`, which clips only the desired half of `myMesh`. Putting `plane2` and `plane3` in the same render pass will result in only 1/4 of `myMesh` rendering.

```
var pass1ClipPlanes = [
        plane1
    ],
    pass2ClipLanes = [
        plane2, // this plane is the inverse of plane 1, so it clips the opposite of plane1
        plane3 // this clips the left/right half of the model
    ];
```

Then when you go to render, clear the draw buffers first, then call two render passes, updating the clip planes between them.

```
// clear the draw buffers
renderer.clear();

// clip the top
myMesh.material.clipPlanes = pass1ClipPlanes;
renderer.render(scene, camera);

// clip the bottom and one side
myMesh.material.clipPlanes = pass2ClipPlanes;
renderer.render(scene, camera);
```

The first pass renders the bottom of the model, and the second pass renders half of the top.

**ETA: Example**

```js
var renderer, scene, camera, controls, stats;

var cube,
  pass1ClipPlanes,
  pass2ClipPlanes;

var WIDTH = window.innerWidth,
  HEIGHT = window.innerHeight,
  FOV = 35,
  NEAR = 1,
  FAR = 1000;

function init() {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "slateGray";

  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    antialias: true,
    alpha: true
  });
  renderer.localClippingEnabled = true;
  renderer.autoClear = false;

  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
  document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
  document.body.style.margin = "0";
  document.body.style.padding = "0";

  scene = new THREE.Scene();

  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(FOV, WIDTH / HEIGHT, NEAR, FAR);
  camera.position.z = 50;
  scene.add(camera);

  controls = new THREE.TrackballControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
  controls.dynamicDampingFactor = 0.5;
  controls.rotateSpeed = 3;

  var light = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 1, Infinity);
  camera.add(light);

  stats = new Stats();
  stats.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
  stats.domElement.style.top = '0';
  document.body.appendChild(stats.domElement);

  resize();
  window.onresize = resize;

  // POPULATE EXAMPLE
  var plane1 = new THREE.Plane(new THREE.Vector3(0, -1, 0), 0),
    plane2 = new THREE.Plane(new THREE.Vector3(0, 1, 0), 0),
    plane3 = new THREE.Plane(new THREE.Vector3(-1, 0, 0), 0);
  pass1ClipPlanes = [plane1];
  pass2ClipPlanes = [plane2, plane3];

  var cubeGeo = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry(10, 10, 10),
    cubeMat = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
      color: "red",
      side: THREE.DoubleSide
    });
  cube = new THREE.Mesh(cubeGeo, cubeMat);
  scene.add(cube);

  animate();
}

function resize() {
  WIDTH = window.innerWidth;
  HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;
  if (renderer && camera && controls) {
    renderer.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    camera.aspect = WIDTH / HEIGHT;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    controls.handleResize();
  }
}

function render() {
  renderer.clear();
  cube.material.clippingPlanes = pass1ClipPlanes;
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
  cube.material.clippingPlanes = pass2ClipPlanes;
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  render();
  controls.update();
  stats.update();
}

function threeReady() {
  init();
}

(function() {
  function addScript(url, callback) {
    callback = callback || function() {};
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.addEventListener("load", callback);
    script.setAttribute("src", url);
    document.head.appendChild(script);
  }

  addScript("https://threejs.org/build/three.js", function() {
    addScript("https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/TrackballControls.js", function() {
      addScript("https://threejs.org/examples/js/libs/stats.min.js", function() {
        threeReady();
      })
    })
  })
})();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. but now I'm getting this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'normal' of null`
    `at wa.copy (three.min.js:458)`
    `at b (three.min.js:130)`
    `at ig.setState (three.min.js:131)`
    `at n (three.min.js:139)`
    `at Xd.renderBufferDirect (three.min.js:171)`
    `at f (three.min.js:38)`
    `at f (three.min.js:38)`
    `at Je.render (three.min.js:42)`

Comment: Can you please switch to using `three.js` (rather than `three.min.js`) so we can see the actual call stack?

Comment: I'm sorry it was because of a typo in Plane's variable name. It works but the problem now is that when I try to move the object It gives this error constantly: `Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'shaderSource' on 'WebGLRenderingContext': parameter 1 is not of type 'WebGLShader`

Comment: @TheJim01 Any chance of an example?

Comment: @Neil I've added a snippet as requested, **BUT** WestLangley's answer is the acepted one, and in my opinion is the correct way of approaching the question as it was asked. I only left my answer here as an alternate method that may give someone an "aha moment" when looking to do something similar in a multi-pass manner.